# editing data in a list while the length of data is different

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

`a = [c0001203, c0334, c0000456, c034554, c00034506].` I need to remove 'c' and all 0 after 'c', until the data starts with a number. The length of each data is variable.  The output should be like this:

`a = [1203, 334, 456, 34506]`. How can I do it without using regular expression?

Thank you.

Comment: what type of data are in the list? are they strings or predefined?

Answer (score 5):

You can drop the `c` and then `.strip()` the `0`'s like:

#### Code:

```
b = [x[1:].lstrip('0') for x in a]
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = ['c0001203', 'c0334', 'c0000456', 'c034554', 'c00034506']
b = [x[1:].lstrip('0') for x in a]
print(b)
```

#### Results:

```
['1203', '334', '456', '34554', '34506']
```

Answer (score 0):

start iterating from `index=1` (ignore 0th index) until you find a non-zero `character`. store the `sub_string` starting from non-zero character till the end

```
def process(str_arr):
    ind = 0
    res = []
    while(ind < len(str_arr)):
        cur_str = str_arr[ind]
        ind_2 = 1
        while(ind_2 < len(cur_str)):
            char = cur_str[ind_2]
            if(char != '0'):
                res.append(cur_str[ind_2:len(cur_str)])
                break;
            ind_2 = ind_2+1
        ind = ind+1
    return res

ret = process(['c0001203', 'c0334', 'c0000456', 'c034554', 'c00034506'])
print(ret)
```

Output :

```
['1203', '334', '456', '34554', '34506']
```